# Box-shadow not appearing OVER a div with lower z-index

Tags: html, css

So guys, I've here a header:

[image: Header with shadow]

As you can see, the box-shadow works just fine. However, putting a background-color on the content `<div>` yields this:

[image: Header with covered shadow]

Visually, the `box-shadow` was covered by the `background-color`. The content `<div>` has lower `z-index` value than the header though. How can I make the `box-shadow` appear over the `<div>` to make it seem like the content is under the header?

If this will help, here is the CSS for both markups:

```
header{ /* the header, obviously */
            background: #fee;
                height: 60px;
               padding: 40px 20px 0px 20px;
         border-bottom: 5px solid #f53301;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px gray;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px gray;
            box-shadow: 0 12px 16px -6px gray;
         border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
               z-index: 9999;
}

#content-inside { /* the content */
    padding:20px;
    z-index:1; /* changed this to -1 but it still didn't work */
    background:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Cheers!

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. BTW, z-index only applies to positioned elements.

Comment: Your `z-index` has no effect at all, because the elements do not have a `position` value different from the default `static` …

Comment: So basically, if I didn't declare a position, it doesn't count? But it has a default value right?

Comment: I see. I'm going to change it now. So that's how it works. Thank you!

Comment: Someone should answer. I'll accept it. Adding position:relative to my header made it work! Thank you people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z-index` only applies to element where the position has been set (i.e. not the default static position). Trying `position:relative` would be the most likely solution here.